# How can I write an efficient grow function for my hash table?

Tags: c++, performance, hashtable

```
        HashEntry** tmp = new HashEntry * [maxSize_ * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxSize_; i++) { 
            tmp[i] = entry_[i]; 
        }
        for (int i = maxSize_; i < maxSize_ * 2; i++) { 
            tmp[i] = nullptr; 
        }
        delete[] entry_; 
        entry_ = tmp; 
        maxSize_ *= 2;
```

My hash table values are stored in the HashEntry struct with the variables `key`, `data`, and `deleted`. My hash table has a threshold where after a certain number of keys are placed in the `entry` variable, the grow function is called automatically. This is my current grow function, but when I try to run it with large hash tables it takes way too long. How can I make this run more efficiently? Isn't the run time of this O(n) as it should be?

EDIT:

```
        int oldSize = maxSize_;
        maxSize_ *= 2;
        HashEntry** tmp = entry_;
        entry_ = new HashEntry * [maxSize_];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxSize_; i++) {
            entry_[i] = nullptr;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < oldSize; i++) {
            if (tmp[i] != nullptr) {
                update(tmp[i]->key_, tmp[i]->data_);
                numRecords_--;
                delete tmp[i];
            }
        }
        delete[] tmp;
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to use realloc.

Comment: A hash table doesn't expand by copying into the same indexes of a larger allocation. You need to rehash based on the new `maxSize_`

Comment: What are you measuring to find "when I try to run it with large hash tables it takes way too long"?

Comment: I'm calling my insert function with various large inputs and seeing how long each  call takes. for my grow function, why can't I just make the HashEntry array larger? do I need to assign the array to a tmp array, reallocate the array, and call my insert function for each entry?

Comment: Yes, you will need to calculate the new hash slot for each entry, based on the new table size.

Comment: I added an edit of what it looks like now, its still a bit slow but better. now my search function can no longer find my hash value though. both my update and search function should work as expected. Is there anything wrong with the above code? or should I be looking in my search function for problems?